# "TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not method" Error Python

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a game and seem to be having some issues here. This is my first time working with sprite sheets, so I apologize if my error is simple.

I apologize in advance for the large amount of code, but unfortunately I believe the problem could be anywhere in this code. The error I am receiving says "TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not method
". This is referring to the all_sprites.draw(screen) command. I know screen is formatted correctly, so its not that. My teacher said it is likely any of the sprites. One of them is not formatted correctly, or doesn't properly interact with the images. Please let me know if you find the solution to my issue, and again I apologize for the large extent of the code.
Thanks!

(I labeled my different files btw, gsettings, gmain, and gsprites. You can see I use them in the imports, shouldn't be a big deal, just thought I would clarify)

FULL EXCEPTION `

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AddisonWeatherhead/PycharmProjects/PyGame/Game 2/gmain.py", line 191, in <module>
    game_play()
  File "/Users/AddisonWeatherhead/PycharmProjects/PyGame/Game 2/gmain.py", line 128, in game_play
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 475, in draw
    self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not method

Process finished with exit code 1
```

gsettings

```
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0,)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
GRAY = (180, 180, 180)
MAROON = (128, 0, 0)
NAVY = (0, 0, 128)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
LIGHT_GRAY = (250, 250, 250)
LIGHT_BLUE = (144, 195, 212)

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 800
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 800
FPS=60
```

gsprites

```
class sprite_sheet():
    def __init__ (self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pygame.image.load(filename)

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image



class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, hero_left_list, hero_right_list, left_shoot, right_shoot):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.hero_left_list=hero_left_list
        self.hero_right_list=hero_right_list
        self.left_shoot=left_shoot
        self.right_shoot=right_shoot

        self.image = self.hero_right_list[0]
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=self.rect.x
        self.rect.y=self.rect.y

        self.changex=0 #Horizontal movement speed
        self.changey=0 #Vertical movement speed

        self.current_frame=0
        self.delay=50 #In millisecond, this will be the delay BETWEEN each frame of a spritesheet (character walking, explosion exploding, etc)
        self.last=pygame.time.get_ticks() #gets the time in milliseconds since pygame.init() was called

        self.running_right=False
        self.running_left=False

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x+=self.changex
        self.rect.y+=self.changey



        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.now=pygame.time.get_ticks() #also gets the time in milliseconds since pygame.init() was called, however this time its LATER than self.delay
            self.running_right=True
            self.changex=5

            if self.now - self.last >self.delay: #Confirming that at least 5 milliseconds has passed since the last call of the function
                self.last=self.now
                self.current_frame=(self.current_frame+1)%(int(len(self.hero_right_list)))
                self.image=self.hero_right_list[self.current_frame]

            self.image=sprite_sheet("hero.png").get_image

        elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.running_left=True
            self.changey=5

            self.image=sprite_sheet.get_image("hero.png", )

        elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.running_left=False
            self.running_right=False
            self.image=sprite_sheet.get_image("hero.png")
```

gmain

```
import pygame
from gsettings import *
from gsprites import *
import time

pygame.init()


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
##########################################################################################
def score(score, lives):
    background = sprite_sheet("background.jpg").get_image(0, 0, 800, 800)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
    screen.blit(background, [0,0])

    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Impact', 40, True, False)
    text = font.render(('Score'+str(score)), True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(text, (200, 50))

##########################################################################################

def game_start():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
    text = "Press enter to play"
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Impact', 50, True, False)
    text_render=font.render(text, True, BLACK)

    background=sprite_sheet("background.jpg").get_image(0, 0, 800, 800)
    screen.blit(background, [0, 0])

    started=False
    while started == False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            quit()

        sprite_sheet("background.jpg").get_image(0, 0, 800, 800)

        screen.blit(text_render, [(DISPLAY_WIDTH / 2) - 150, (DISPLAY_HEIGHT / 2)])
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            screen.blit(background, [0, 0])
            print('last')
            return True


        print(started)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)

##########################################################################################
def game_play():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

    hero_right_list = []
    for x in range(6):
        for y in range(2, 3):
            right_image = sprite_sheet("hero.png").get_image(80 * x, 94 * y, 80, 94)
            hero_right_list.append(right_image)
            # Player is 80 wide 94 tall


    hero_left_list = []
    for image in hero_right_list:
        hero_left_list.append(pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False))



    explosion_list = []
    for x in range(25):
        for y in range(1, 2):
            explosion_image = sprite_sheet("Explosion.png").get_image(192 * x, 195 * y, 192, 195)
            explosion_list.append(explosion_image)



    shoot_right=(sprite_sheet("hero.png").get_image(0, 94*3, 80, 94))
    shoot_left=pygame.transform.flip(shoot_right, True, False)

    #Creating Sprite groups
    all_sprites=pygame.sprite.Group()

    enemy_sprites=pygame.sprite.Group()
    player_sprite=pygame.sprite.Group()
    laser_sprites=pygame.sprite.Group()
    explosion_sprite=pygame.sprite.Group()


    #sprite objects
    player=Player(hero_left_list, hero_right_list, shoot_left, shoot_right)
    all_sprites.add(player)
    player_sprite.add(player)


    for val in range(10):
        enemy_right=Enemy('right')
        enemy_left=Enemy('left')
        enemy_sprites.add(enemy_right)
        enemy_sprites.add(enemy_left)
        all_sprites.add(enemy_right)
        all_sprites.add(enemy_left)

        global game_score
        game_score = 0


    started=True
    while started==True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                   # events to end the game
                   if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                       quit()
        player.update()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            player.image=shoot_right

        laser_hits=pygame.sprite.groupcollide(laser_sprites, enemy_sprites, True, True)
        for hit in laser_hits:
            game_score+=5
            explosion=Explosion(explosion_list)
            explosion_sprite.add(explosion)
            all_sprites.add(explosion)
            enemy=Enemy()
            enemy_sprites.add(enemy)
            all_sprites.add(enemy)

        score(score, 5)

        #enemy_sprites.draw(screen) #NO ISSUES
        #explosion_sprite.draw(screen) #NO ISSUES
        #laser_sprites.draw(screen) #NO ISSUES
        player_sprite.draw(screen) #ISSUES


        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(FPS)

##########################################################################################

def game_over(score):
    over_screen=pygame.display.set_mode([DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT])
    clock.tick(FPS)

    end_message_1="GAME OVER!"
    end_message_2="Your score was", score

    end_message_3="Replay"
    end_message_4="Quit"

    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans', 75, True, False)

    #rendering text

    end_message_1_render=font.render(end_message_1, True, RED)
    end_message_2_render=font.render(end_message_2, True, BLACK)

    end_message_3_render=font.render(end_message_3, True, BLACK)
    end_message_4_render=font.render(end_message_4, True, BLACK)
    started=False
    while started == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

        clicked=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        pos=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if pos[0]>0 and pos[0]<100 and pos[1]>0 and pos[1]<100:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] ==1:
                started=False

        over_screen.fill(WHITE)

        over_screen.blit(end_message_1, [(DISPLAY_WIDTH//2), (DISPLAY_HEIGHT//2)])
        over_screen.blit(end_message_2, ((DISPLAY_WIDTH//2), ((DISPLAY_HEIGHT//2)+50)))
        over_screen.blit(end_message_3, [((DISPLAY_WIDTH // 2)-20), ((DISPLAY_HEIGHT // 2) + 120)])
        over_screen.blit(end_message_4, [((DISPLAY_WIDTH // 2)+20), ((DISPLAY_HEIGHT // 2) + 120)])

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.clock.tick(FPS)

    started=True
##########################################################################################








game_start()


while True:
    game_play()
    game_over(game_score)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Can you please show the whole exception message ? (with function calls history)

Comment: @LouisSugy just edited, let me know if there is anything else I need to include. Thanks!

Comment: I guess `Explosion` and `Enemy` are classes inheriting from `Sprite`, right?

Comment: One of the sprites must have a problem, try to comment all the `all_sprites.add(...)` statements except for one, and change this one, to find which sprites create a problem and which don't

Comment: @LouisSugy ah yes I will try that. Also yes, Explosion and Enemy are classes from the gsprite file, I didn't include those because I was trying to keep the bulk of the code out. If you think it would be beneficial, I can include that. Thanks again! Ill check the different .draw() error messages when I get a chance

Comment: No need to add them since their code is not really important

Comment: @LouisSugy I made a couple changes so you can see what calls work. The issue is definitely in the player sprite, but I can't tell where. Also, when you are testing, make sure to press the right arrow, as that is the only one I coded. Let me know if you find the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the line of the error, `spr.image` is a method, not a `pygame.Surface`, which is what's expected by `surface_blit()`.

EDIT (in response to comments):

The error is on line 475 of `sprite.py`.

Comment: I see, so where in the code do I make the mistake of something being a sprite rather than a pygame surface?

Comment: I see that, but that is for sprites. I understand that the sprite module is having an issue because of a parameter, what I dont understand is where in my code (like gsprites, gmain, or gsettings) I make the error that leads to the error in sprites that you mention. Any ideas as to where in my code the issue lies?